A road to algebraic geometry
I am a person who leans strongly towards algebraic geometry and am looking forward to studying it in depth. I am going to lay out my plan to approach algebraic geometry, and I hope some people here can improve it or make some important suggestions.
My plan is to study real analysis, topology, complex analysis, algebra (linear and abstract), here are the books that I am studying from:
Principles of Mathematical Analysis by Walter Rudin (currently studying).
Linear algebra done right by Axler (currently studying).
Abstract algebra by Dummit and Foote.
Complex Analysis by Ahlfors.
Algebraic curves by Fulton.
So those books are what I am planning to study before approaching algebraic geometry. After studying those books, I am planning to study from Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, or from Vakil's foundations of algebraic geometry. Please inform me if there are any improvements I can make to my plan, and what to do after it.
Edit: This question is different than the question "A road map to algebraic geometry" because it asks about the specific prerequisites such as complex analysis and abstract algebra. My question is asking for book recommendations of algebraic geometry prerequisites. As to the other question, prerequisites like the ones mentioned here are barely mentioned.

Also commutative algebra, general topology and complex analysis
